What power lets you modify game actions? (Power Profiles are weird)
Lightning Disarm has the following text in Power Profiles

Burst Area on Strength for Disarming, Selective - 2 points per rank (maximum rank equal to Strength)

This threw me off because...well, that's a Disarm with a Area of Effect, a concept that currently cannot exist normally as per RAW as far as I know given Enhanced Trait by the definition of Trait refers to "abilities, skills, advantages, and powers" (pg. 310 PHB).
My question is pretty simple: What power is this?
If it was Enhanced Power (Burst Area, Selective), Variable Descriptor (Attacks) this could potentially do the same thing but to all kinds of attacks rather than just Disarming, but Lightning Disarm seems to just...not have a Power associated with it, just Extras on Disarm. Is there something in the books that allows this? Is there anything telling you what game actions you can and can't modify with power extras? What are the page numbers and such for these things I must know lmao.

Indeed, it is using Enhanced Trait, applying the extra to the pseudo power of your Strength Damage.

Strength provides a “built-in” Damage effect: the ability to hit things! You can apply effect modifiers to the damage your Strength inflicts, making it Penetrating or even an Area effect! You can also have Alternate Effects for your Strength Damage; see the Alternate Effect modifier for details. Like other Damage effects, a character’s Strength Damage is close range and instant duration by default.

This is page 156 of my Deluxe Heroes Handbook. My understanding of the entry is that they are applying the Area Extra on Strength, Selective, Limited to Strength Damage, Limited the Disarming aspect of Strength Damage. That makes it 1 PP per ranks of Strength Damage that you want to be Area for Disarming.
As a side note, yes, the Power Profiles are weird. They're official releases, but they are not primary canon (which is why, when they're used in modules, they're written out explicitly), they're largely written by several different contractors who worked independently, each section was initially released as its own PDF, and it's not uncommon for them to implement the same thing with very different descriptors and ending point costs. It's probably better to think of them as suggestions of how you might use the system, much like you might get from your fellow players, rather than RAW.

As a side note, yes, the Power Profiles are weird. They're official releases, but they are not primary canon (which is why, when they're used in modules, they're written out explicitly), they're largely written by several different contractors who worked independently, each section was initially released as its own PDF, and it's not uncommon for them to implement the same thing with very different descriptors and ending point costs. It's probably better to think of them as suggestions of how you might use the system, much like you might get from your fellow players, rather than RAW.

That comment should be part of the answer.

So the issue here is this isn't correct. While Strength has a Damage Effects of, Enhanced Trait applies to Traits, which are classified as "abilities, skills, advantages, and powers" (pg. 310). While Strength is a ability, its Damage Effect is none of the above. If Enhanced Trait did work on effects, you could enhance things like the rate at which Heat Environments apply their effect like Regeneration with your healing over time, which would be cool and I would love to try that, but for your answer to be correct I need proof that Effects are Traits.

@FriendlyNeighborhoodChicken Other than that they specifically state that you can apply power modifiers to that strength damage? For what it is worth, I personally think that it opens up a can of worms in terms of people trying to create a set of loose modifiers that can be mixed and matched, compared to the intent of a modifier always being on if bought, but that is a difference of a Power Point or two in most cases, to create an alternate effect.

And, well, it does specifically call out that it is modifying your strength, which is a trait. Admittedly, they're only modifying a part of it, but that's where the flaws come in.

"For Disarming" isn't a flaw, where Burst Area and Selective total at 2/R, where it being based on Strength Based Damage has that part of its cost just on your Strength, with the ranks of the extras being based on it. The fact it's only a part of Strength is what makes it a effect of Strength, not Strength itself, and therefore invalid for Enhanced Trait. Will say I'm kinda baffled because I'm 99% sure its not Enhanced Trait yet unsure what it is. Wonder if there's powers worded like this outside of Power Profiles.

I want to be clear I would love to be able to do this sort of stuff with Enhanced Trait I just want to make sure its RAW, or if there's some other thing that lets you do this. It being a Enhanced Trait would mean you can add flaws like Increased Action 2 and the modifications much cheaper than they'd otherwise be as a Instant Standard Action Attack Power.
